How can I use a ? in a URL to change JavaScript variables?
I can't figure out how the ? URL separator works, which I need to use for a project.
I made a variable that would alert it's content when the page was opened, opened the deployment with ?variable="working", and expected it to alert working, but instead it alerted what the variable was originally set to.
var variable = "Not Working";
alert(url);


This is a query string which you must manually parse from the url. It wont affect the HTTP request, it's like extra text content at the end of your request address. There are rules and encodings for URI components and specifically query strings or URLSearchParams, but they're not automatically imported as a variable.

It's not really clear to me what you're trying to describe based on the example code shown.  Can you update this to a [mcve] which demonstrates your attempt and indicate what specifically isn't working as expected in that attempt?

The short version is that changing a query parameter does not automatically change variable values.

You must manually parse the url for your variables.
this is an example of getting the search params from a query string in the url:
window.addEventListner("load", () => {
    const href = window.location.href; //assuming ?foo=bar
    const queryString = href.split("?")[1];
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
    const foo = searchParams.get("foo");
    console.log(foo) //bar
});

As suggested in a comment, you could also use the URL constructor just as easily:
window.addEventListner("load", () => {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href); //assuming ?foo=bar
    const foo = url.searchParams.get("foo");
    console.log(foo) //bar
});


Why not https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL?

you could use const url = new URL(window.location.href) and then url.searchParams.get("foo") just as easily. Then you don't have to split the href. In this example I had a bigger focus on URLSearchParams than all the other properties of URL.
